# Set ItemProcessor dynamically through Partitioner

Tags: spring-batch

I want to run step in several threads, but also I want each thread to use different processors, as, for example, we can make reader read from different sources.

This is my xml config:

```
    <batch:job id="job">
        <batch:step id="readFromQueuesMaster">
            <batch:partition step="readFromQueuesSlave" partitioner="queuePartitioner">
                <batch:handler grid-size="5" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
            </batch:partition>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <batch:step id="readFromQueuesSlave">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="queueReader"
                         processor="#{stepExecutionContext[itemProcessor]}"
                         writer="flatFileItemWriter"
                         commit-interval="10"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

This is my partitioner:

```
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
        ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
        value.put("itemProcessor", someMethodReturningProcessor(i));
        result.put("partition" + i, value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Obviously, using processor="#{stepExecutionContext[itemProcessor]}" is not working.

Comment: if you just want to get processor per thread, you can make the specific processor stepScoped, if you want a completely different processor (and processing) per partition... well i am lost, partition semantics require to have "same" processing per partition